# How to convert string format "yyyyMMdd HHmmss_fff" to date T-SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I'm getting this string "20150930 092622_647" and have to save it to a datetime column but I can convert it.

I know about the CONVERT but the closest expression style I found was 112 the problem is the time not the date here.

```
 CONVERT(DATETIME, REPLACE( '20150930 092622_647', '_', ' '), 112)
```

Comment: What does 092622_647 represent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the style unless you are converting the other way... from a `datetime` to a character based type.

This expression will probably get you what you need:

```
select convert(datetime,stuff(stuff(stuff('20150930 092622_647',16,1,'.'),14,0,':'),12,0,':'))
```